# OnPageChangeListener still active after changing fragment, causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-viewpager, listener, illegalstateexception

After replacing a ViewPager with a single fragment as such:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction ().replace ( R.id.content_frame, fragment ).commit ();
```

If I scroll to the right - which shouldn't me possible because there is only one page - I get an IllegalStateExceptio on *onPageSelected*, because apparently the OnPageChangeListener is still active.

How do I approach this?

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener ( new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener () {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected ( int position ) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem ( position );
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled ( int arg0, float arg1, int arg2 ) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged ( int arg0 ) {
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hackish workaround. There's got to be a better way, but it works.  To disable paging, set the viewpager adapter to one with 0 pages.

```
public class EmptyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public EmptyPagerAdapter ( FragmentManager fm ) {
    super ( fm );
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem ( int index ) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount () {
    return 0;
}
```

}